# Why is the space describing Bernoulli scheme compact?

Tags: probability-theory, metric-spaces, compactness

I've run into this exercise from Klenke's book "Probability theory".

Let $E$ be the finite set of possible outcomes. Let $\Omega = E^{\mathbb{N}}$ be the space of all possible outcomes of the repeated experiment.

Define the metric $d$ on $\Omega$ by

$$
\begin{equation}
d(w, w') = \begin{cases}
            2^{-\inf{\{n\in \mathbb{N} \ : \ w_n \neq w'_n  \}}},&\text{if} \ w \neq w' \\  
            0, & \text{if}  \ w= w'
           \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$$

My question is why $(\Omega, d)$ is a compact metric space.

What are open sets in this space?

Comment: This defines the product topology on $E^{\Bbb N}$. By Tychhonoff's theorem this topology is compact.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, can you prove it by definition?

Comment: @Elnur the open cover you propose doesn't actually cover $\Omega$: the union misses the constant sequence $(1,1,1,\ldots)$. You will see that as soon as you add an open neighbourhood of this constant sequence, you can find finite subcovers.

Comment: @MarcPaul, thanks

Comment: Well, actually, I've founded a way to prove it. 1) Prove that $\Omega$ is a sequentially compact set 2) Every sequentially compact metric space is a countably compact metric space 3) Prove all open sets in $\Omega$ are countable set